# Python TKinter Is there a way to dynamically link variables and widgets to save RAM/memory

Tags: python, tkinter, memory

I am making a physics calculator that involves splitting and organizing my calculator by topic. this means i have lots of widgets to navigate the menu to get to the problem. i don't want to delete the widgets as this would remove all the details of the widgets which would make my code unnecessarily complicated and long. is there a way to dynamically link the variables or widgets so that the program can run more smoothly?

I do not know of any way to do this so i cannot provide any code. If there is no way to do it i would also appreciate knowing this.

Comment: Have you looked at `.grid_remove()`/`.place_remove()`/`.pack_forget()`?

Answer (score 1):

> a way to dynamically link the variables or widgets so that the program can run more smoothly?

I suggest taking look at [`StringVar`](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-stringvar/) which might be linked with suitable widgets, consider following simple example

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Entry, StringVar
root = Tk()
str_var = StringVar(root,"hello")
label = Label(root, textvariable=str_var)
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=str_var)
label.pack()
entry.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This creates window with Label and Entry, as you change text in Entry corresponding change is made to Label. You might also find `.trace` method of `StringVar` instance useful as it allows you to register callback i.e. function to be called when value was changed.